# Map react component import paths to same paths as a component in a module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, path, tsconfig

I have a react project that uses a module for its ui. To customize the components i have to copy the components from the module into my project.

My Problem:
The copied components have loads of imports with relative file paths which are all wrong now. How do i fix this problem as easily as possible?

Using the configts to change the paths didnt do anything

Comment: What kind of customization? It would be helpful to specify the module/library as the complexity of this question and answer varies based on that. If it is simply styling you should instead use the `className` property (typically exposed on UI components in any good library), or it may have some alternative name like `style`, or `sx` (MUI). If you are changing internal logic I would sooner use low level JS apis to manipulate the component, either before or after it is rendered (IE. React.Children, window.getDocumentById, etc...). I can write an answer/explanation of whichever method you need.

Comment: element-web (riot-web) takes its components from the matrix-react-sdk, but to overwrite the matrix-react-sdk components i have to copy them over to element-web but then all the import paths are wrong. How do i fix this without rewriting all the imports again